# Images from Paint.NET failed inside Eclipse

Tags: java, png, alpha, paint.net

Under the following configuration:

> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers - Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)
>
> Java Version 8 Update 45 Build 1.8.0_45-b15
>
> Paint.NET 4.0.5 (Final 4.5.5454.39504)

Each time i use Transparency (Alpha) PNGs inside *Paint.NET*, when using images on *Java* code inside *Eclipse*, i reach a *Java* exception:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Rescaling cannot be performed on an indexed image at java.awt.image.RescaleOp.filter (Unknown Source).

Anybody experienced this before? How can i solve this?

Comment: I am still... intrigued about this....

Answer (score 1):

You probably saved the PNG at 8-bit color depth without knowing it. The default bit-depth for saving a PNG in Paint.NET is "Auto", which means it will use whatever bit-depth produces the smallest file size *and* which results in no loss of fidelity. If your image uses less than 256 unique colors, than 8-bit will be used.

8-bit is an indexed, or "palletized," image format, hence the error about "an indexed image."

Set the bit-depth to 32 and try again :)